# Cannot compile linux kernel in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I received a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I installed the Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) and managed to connect it to putty. Now, I am referencing the offical website to configure and install the linux kernel into my Raspberry Pi. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html

These are the commands that I've executed so far (in sequence):

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt upgrade
3. sudo apt-get autoremove
4. sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev make
5. git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
6. cd linux
   KERNEL=kernel8
   make bcm2711_defconfig
7. make -j4 Image.gz modules dtbs

I encountered an error while executing point 7. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)